# How to get image's src attribute from MongoDB to external JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ejs, multer

I'm trying to change the img's src attribute through external javascript but I couldn't find a way to do so...

Best I can do is passing through the data-attribute but since it's stringified it won't work. The goal is getting their full path from external javascript. Can I make this happen?

```
<body
... 

<div class='test' data-test-value='<%= JSON.stringify(image) %>'></div>

<script src="/js/external.js"></script>
</body>
```

```
// external.js
let source = $('.test').attr('data-test-value')
let src = `data:image/${source.image.contentType};base64, ${source.image.data.toString('base64')}>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass it to JavaScript as an object and store it in a global variable, and then convert typed array to base64 string and assign it to src attribute.

```
// global variable
const source = <%- JSON.stringify(image); %> 

// external.js
// note: need to turn typed array to base64 string with JS

console.log('JSON image global: ', source);

let src = `data:image/${source.image.contentType};base64, ${btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(source.image.data)))}`;
```

And if you only need base64 string, and want to avoid conversion on the client, you could simply convert image to base64 on the server, and also pass it to JavaScript as a global variable:

```
// alternatively, you could convert image to base64 right on the server
const base64Image = '<%= source.image.toString('base64') %>';
```

**edit**

the image variable must be declared as a global variable in the template before external.js is loaded:

```
<script>
    // global variable, not within functions/methods etc.
    const source = <%- JSON.stringify(image); %> 

     $(document).ready(function(){
        //...
     });

</script>

<script src="/js/external.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did you define `const source` in internal javascript inside .ejs file? I did so and it's not been passed to external javascript, it says source is not defined.

Comment: yeah. make sure `source` is in the script tag _above_ the script tag with external.js, i.e. it must run/be defined before external.js is processed

Comment: make sure the variable is global, if it's inside some module or object, then it won't be accessible, which seems to be the case. For example, if you use jQuery, and it's within `$(document).ready`, then it won't be accessible